# Oauth issue "unauthorized" in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I have an implementation in a spring application with Oauth, but can get a token:

OAuth2ServerConfigAuthorizationServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfigAuthorizationServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/entuzona/**").authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
 }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }

    }
}
```

OAuth2ClientConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.sprhib")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class OAuth2ClientConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("teste").password("teste").authorities("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

I am making post and gets with postman:

POST request:

```
http://localhost:8080/entuzona/oauth/token
grant_type: password
username: teste
password: teste
```

And with a GET:

```
http://localhost:8080/entuzona/oauth/token?grant_type=password&cliend_id=clientapp&client_secret=123456&username=teste&password=teste

{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Do you know why I am getting this error in both cases?
Shoul I put something in the header for getting the token?

Versions.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing this code:

@Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
      oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
  }